# CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER get html source page

Tags: abap

I use CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER
I need to read the source code of the page into a table after loading. How to do it?

thanks

Comment: Do you *have* to do it via `cl_gui_html_viewer`? Perhaps it might be easier to just load the HTML code directly from the URL using `cl_http_client` without the detour over the gui?

Comment: @Philipp I know it's easier. I have an old 2006 system. And there is no SSL support. admins not install crypto libraryю The only chance to read the source. So far, I have resolved this issue through an intermediary server. MSSQL but I am interested in whether it is possible to do through cl_gui_html_viewer. thanks